# Precision of number not maintained when saved via Export

Tags: export, machine-precision

Assume that the output of my calculation is `a` and is a number such as:

> `a = 100.1252135246354847;`

`N[a]` gives me `100.125`

However, when I try to save my data, `a` via export such as :

> `Export["/path/to/file/with/extension/dat", N[a]]`

My eventual filename.dat has `100.12521352463548` and not `100.125`.
So is the precision of digits/most significant digits for display only?

I also tried `NumberForm[a,6]` and I get  `` NumberForm[100.1252135246354847`18.000543455259304, 6] `` in my data file!

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit (possible solution):

Replacing `N[a]` with `SetPrecision[a,5]` helped.
I wasn't sure if I should have this in the ANSWER section because the solution may be quite trivial and may not warrant being in the answer section.
Any thoughts on that (whether or not I should answer this question or let the solution remain as an appended "edit")

Comment: By the way, after you enter N[a], edit the output (or press Ctrl+Shift+L) to see the full machine form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the path between the quotation marks.

```
a = 100.1252135246354847;  
Export[StringJoin["", ToString[N[a, 6]], ".dat"], a]
```

100.125.dat

Answer (score 5):

Replacing `N[a]` with `SetPrecision[a,5]` helped. 
The above answer by Fred Daniel Kline helps too but isn't really what I am looking for.