# Export numeric data with preset decimal places

Tags: export, machine-precision

I have a table of pairs of numbers, each with 300 decimal places, which are all important. If saved using Export["data.dat", data] and then imported back via Import["data.dat"] - then the 300 decimal places will become about 8 decimal places. What is the easiest way to overcome this? I don't really need the data file to be compatible with anything other than Mathematica.

This question is similar to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9930/precision-of-number-not-maintained-when-saved-via-export).

Comment: If you only need to save data for re-import back to mathematica use `.m` or `.mb` format.

Comment: @george2079 What difference does specifying the file extension explicitly as `.m` or `.mb` make? Looks like if I use `Export` with the third argument being `"List"`, then the output file will be basically a text file, be its extension `.m` or `.mb`. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: correcting myself that should be `.mx` not `.mb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment, the native mathematica package format precisely preserves the definition of symbols:

```
 lst = {1.3566789543235679098765432344564335, N[Pi, 50]};
 FullForm[lst[[1]]]
```

> 1.3566789543235679098765432344564335`34.132477087997515

```
 Export["test.m", lst];
 newlist = Import["test.m"];
 FullForm[newlist[[1]]]
```

> 1.3566789543235679098765432344564335`34.132477087997515

The "List" format chops to the nearest ascii representation and converts back on import,

```
Export["testfile", lst, "List"];
newlst = Import["testfile", "List"];
FullForm[newlst[[1]]]
```

> 1.3566789543235679098765432344564340000000000000000000000001`33.132477087997515

The difference is very subtle and perhaps inconsequential (here actually one bit difference in a 100+ bit binary representation ). I haven't tested it but I expect `.m` is faster too if you have large files to save. Of course the downside is `.m` is a unique format that would be difficult for anything else to parse.

Note the third argument to `Export` overrides whatever extension the file name has.  The third argument corresponding to `.m` is `"Package"`.

Also ".mx" is binary, which will be faster and smaller than ".m", but may not be portable across systems and versions.  (Anybody know the "third argument" name for mx? )

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I also noticed the following difference between `.m` and `"List"`: suppose that `data` is constructed as `data=Table[{RandomReal[],RandomReal[]},{10}]`. Then if it is saved via `Export` into an `.m` file, and then imported back in via `Import`, then `data[[All,2]]` does what it's supposed to do, i.e., extracts all of the second components of `data`. However, when the data export is done using `"List"` as the third option of `Export`, then `data[[All,2]]` no longer works after `data` is imported via `Import`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

The `Export` `List` format may be what your need.  For instance, with

```
lst = {1.3566789543235679098765432344564335, N[Pi, 50]}
```

(not 300 digits, but a lot.)

```
Export["C:/Temp/tst", lst, "List"];
newlst = Import["C:/Temp/tst", "List"];
newlst
(* {1.35667895432356790987654323445643, 
    3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751} *)
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you.